# How to change IFRAME content on a server side?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I've tried to look for an answer in the posts, but still don't have a clear one.
This is my scenario:
on one of the pages I have an IFRAME that is getting content from another domain. The frame looks odd, the style is totally different from the main site. On top of that by submitting the form it targets new page and I’d prefer the user to stay on the same page. 
So I thought maybe I can change a few things  - styling and the target of the form within that IFRAME. As far as I understand it is not possible by using JavaScript since it’s coming from another domain.  I was thinking about server side script (PHP for example) that would load IFRAME content into a string first and then replace style href’s, change "target = _blank" to something else and finally pass the content back to the page.

This is what I have in mind. 
Originally it looks like this:

```
<!-- iframe src="http://www.otherdomain.com/cgi-bin/querypackage.cgi?code=ent1"></iframe-->
```

I replace it with this:

```
<iframe src=”frameprocessor.php"></iframe>
```

All the magic happens in frameprocessor.php.

Is it possible? Maybe I’m overcomplicating things and the answer is much simpler……

Thank you!

Comment: even if you get what you want you still cant execute javascript to get private data from another domain so no. :) that being said if you own the other script and want content generated on another host why not just get it with php passing all data needed to generate it and `include` it. Even better use an api that returns just the data u need and theme it on the correct site.

Comment: Thank yo for your reply! I don't own the script. The company supplying the content for IFRAME is not providing with any customization options. Whatever can be done has to be done on my end.

Comment: you can fetch the page from php using fopen or get_file_contents("http: //whatever"); and strreplace or so to style it. but if you need for example a user to be logged in on that external page there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 1):

You can not modify the contents within an iFrame. Especially it's contents and forms. You can alter the outter appearance (ie; the height/ width/ borders, etc...) But due to XSS issues (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Frame_Scripting) - you wont be able to modify content within the iFrame.

What I do suggest however, is maybe an API request to the domain? Or maybe building a cURL solution to post data into the website through an external form (webhooks).

Comment: Exactly. And if youre trying to send a request to a third party page / read personal data you do not own - give up.

Answer (score 0):

Just shooting in the dark here, but try using contentDocument of the iFrame object?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp

EDIT: since you've added the idea of using php, you could use get contents through php to fetch the page and alter the stuff you want to change and output the delta.

I'm kinda curious if the contentDocument thing would work though, I've never personally tried that (i shy away from iFrames!)

Comment: w3schools should never be linked to, and a link alone is not an answer

Comment: i agree but w3schools is a good page for complete begginers. and the comment on parsing / replacing it with php is a good answer.